# Оптимизация HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, оптимизация

Вопрос по оптимизации HTML кода. Имеется подобная структура.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
```

На мобильном разрешении элемент с классом "parent" не требуется. Но если я пропишу для него в CSS правило display: none, будет ли это значить, что и дочерние его элементы так же последуют этому правилу. Так же вопрос: значит ли правило display: none, что браузер игнорирует этот элемент и (!) не тратит на него оперативную память?

Comment: Тратит конечно, этот элемент прекрасно доступен из js со всеми его возможностями

Comment: хорошо, можно ли этого как-нибудь избежать? чтобы элемент ну вообще ничего не ел

Comment: Только удалить его целиком и полностью из кода

Comment: @Chamond Существовал, но места не занимал? :)

Comment: глупый вопрос задал, каюсь) решение очевидное и неподходящее. Ну, во всяком случае, просчитывать и рендерить его не придется, а это уже очень хорошо

Answer (score 2):

Дочерние элементы не будут отображаться, поскольку сам элемент временно удаляется, а значит что и память не затрачивается.
Более детально вы можете ознакомится [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display).

Comment: Почему не затрачивается-то?

Comment: "Временно удаляет элемент из документа." - это что, погрешности перевода?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304994/5598926